# Error when trying to import an AES wrapped key in Keystore

Tags: android, keystore

I'm trying to import an AES wrapped key (with a RSA 3072 bit long key). This is my code snippet:

```
fun importWrappedJey(keySpec: KeySpec) {
    val spec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keySpec.alias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_WRAP_KEY)
        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
        .setCertificateNotBefore(keySpec.notBeforeDate.toDate())
        .setCertificateNotAfter(keySpec.expireDate.toDate())
        .setKeyValidityStart(keySpec.notBeforeDate.toDate())
        .setKeyValidityEnd(keySpec.expireDate.toDate())
        .build()

    val wrappedKeyEntry: WrappedKeyEntry = WrappedKeyEntry(keySpec.wrap, keySpec.wrappingKeyAlias, "RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding", spec)
    keyStore.setEntry(keySpec.alias, wrappedKeyEntry, null)
}
```

And I'm getting this error message (when the last line of the previous methods executes):

```
android.security.KeyStoreException: Incompatible purpose (internal Keystore code: -3 message: In import_wrapped_key.

Caused by:
    0: In KeystoreSecurityLevel::upgrade_keyblob_if_required_with.
    1: In utils::upgrade_keyblob_if_required_with: Calling km_op.
    2: Error::Km(ErrorCode(-3))) (public error code: 13 internal Keystore code: -3)
```

I understand that my error is probably because the key has a purpose that is not the same of the `keySpec`. I decrypted the wrapped key and see this:

```
PrivateKeyInfo SEQUENCE (6 elem)
  version Version INTEGER 0
  privateKeyAlgorithm AlgorithmIdentifier [?] OCTET STRING (256 byte) 1D29104B29B70982D65BEEB4ADDAE0A4A42F0E185B58FE8C42...…
  privateKey PrivateKey OCTET STRING (12 byte) CA7D53E4889C9C8A0A29023F
  SEQUENCE (2 elem)
    INTEGER 3
    SEQUENCE (6 elem)
      [1] (1 elem)
        SET (2 elem)
          INTEGER 0
          INTEGER 1
      [2] (1 elem)
        INTEGER 32
      [3] (1 elem)
        INTEGER 128
      [4] (1 elem)
        SET (2 elem)
          INTEGER 1
          INTEGER 2
      [6] (1 elem)
        SET (2 elem)
          INTEGER 1
          INTEGER 64
      [503] (1 elem)
        NULL
  OCTET STRING (16 byte) 0132F4C990E5...
  OCTET STRING (16 byte) 87D8A675B94E9...
```

In the purposes I saw encrypt and decrypt

```
  [1] (1 elem)
    SET (2 elem)
      INTEGER 0
      INTEGER 1
```

I should add also the `INTEGER 5`?

```
 enum class KeyPurpose : uint32_t {
    ENCRYPT = 0,
    DECRYPT = 1,
    SIGN = 2,
    VERIFY = 3,
    DERIVE_KEY = 4,  // since 3.0
    WRAP_KEY = 5,    // since 3.0
};
```

https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/keystore/tags#purpose

I'm a bit confused because until now this was working.